# Storing user data for free

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, api, google-docs

I will make a website where users log in to see the site's info organized in a way which is specific to each user, depending on the settings which they can set/save while logged in. But they won't be adding content or uploading anything. So I guess, it won't be a lot of data - just a couple lines of text for each user.

So, to start out, I'd like to use something free to store that user data. Dropbox or Google  docs, my own compter.... I dont know.

And then later, when I get enough users to make the investment worthwhile, pay for a more legitimate solution.

My question is, in the meantime, what is the best way to store that user data? Should I use javascript and Google docs API to read/write to a spreadsheet?

What is going to be most convenient when my user base has grown enough and it comes time to move all that over to a larger system?

And are there any other concerns I should be thinking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using sqlite3 or something for a database setup. They can be very small files and easily manageable. In the long-run sqlite3 isn't a great choice. You would want to move to a heftier database assuming you rake in a lot of users.

Comment: Ok, thanks. An where would I want to host a sqlite3 database? Is there any free options for that?

Comment: sqlite3 is pretty cool in that you don't really need to "host" a database, the database is stored in a local file. A 5-minute google search will get you rolling with that.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using a lightweight DBMS like MySQL. If you want, you can serve it locally using your computer, but don't expect it to handle a lot of traffic. It'd be better to find an old computer and use that as a server.

Comment: Thanks. Any recommendation for software or method of turning an old computer into a server?

Comment: Apache sever is a common option

Answer (score 2):

What is your hosting solution? Many include free mySQL databases which should be enough.

Comment: Not sure yet. Something free until I get enough users to validate to project/concept. Any recommendation?

Comment: You didn't mention a platform. PHP? ASP?

Comment: Probably not PHP, I don't think many free hosting options support that. Not sure about ASP. I guess that's kind of what I'm asking -There's more than one solution - trying to find out which ones people recommend.